# Return byte[] from ASP.net MVC 4 WEB API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller method which returns byte[].

```
[ActionName("testbytes")]
public byte[] GetTestBytes() {
    var b = new byte[] {137, 80, 78, 71};
    return b;
}
```

when i hit the api, i get following result.

```
<base64Binary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">iVBORw==</base64Binary>
```

Also when i hit this api from custom HttpClient, i get 10 bytes as a response.
Following is the code of custom HttpClient.

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetTestBytes() {
    var uri = "apiPath/testbytes";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var bytes = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        }
        return bytes;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am expecting 4 bytes while i am receiving 10 bytes in response.

Comment: What do you mean you expect 4 bytes? That is 4 bytes. http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php?lang=en

Comment: yes. I should get 4 bytes i.e. 137, 80, 78, 71

Comment: That IS 4 bytes. Base64 encoding encodes binary into printable characters, so it takes more than 4 bytes to store 4 bytes, in this case 10 bytes.

Comment: @Aron. Why API returns response in Base64 encoding? Is there any way to stop this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Markand: When you are hitting API, the response returned will be wrapped by double quotes ("responsebodygoeshere")

So following byte array

> var b = new byte[] {137, 80, 78, 71};

is serialized as **"iVBORw=="**

Due to this when calling httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
you will get bytes representation of **"iVBORw=="** (which will be 10 bytes) and not for **iVBORw==**

Optionally you can read response content as string and then trim the quotes and then convert it to the byte[] (There may be better approach. :))

i.e. `var response = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Trim('"')`

then call following method to get bytes

```
var bytesResponse =  Convert.FromBase64String(response);
```